# Question on Child-Parent SOQL Limits

Tags: soql, documentation, child-to-parent

I'm reading the documentation on SOQL limits in prep for my Salesforce Dev 1 cert. I'm not sure I understand the description of the limit on child-parent relationships for custom objects.

It states:

> No more than 55 child-to-parent relationships can be specified in a query. A custom object allows up to 25 relationships, so you can reference all the child-to-parent relationships for a custom object in one query.

It is unclear what it means by **so you can reference all the child-to-parent relationships...**

Answer (score 1):

Let’s say you have an object A that has max lookup relationships (25); having 55 as the limit of parent relationships you can specify on a query means you can access all –directly– related objects to object A (25) within such query

Comment: Isn't the max lookup relationships actually 40?

Comment: You are correct! Apparently the limit is currently at 40, with an option to increase it to 50 (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000331427&type=1&mode=1). It seems like the originally quoted doc (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_limits.htm) needs adjustment. However, the affirmation holds, you can query up to 55 child to parent relationships, then, you can query all the —child to parent— relationships for any given object.